# How was an infrared picture of the entire universe taken?

Tags: universe, observational-astronomy

[image]
(click to enlarge)

How was this picture of the supposed entire universe taken in infrared? Also, why does it seem as though almost all of the matter is in a line formation over the center? It makes sense why most matter would be concentrated in the center, but why is it in a line?

Comment: 1) It is not the universe but a Galaxy.
2) You should give a reference.
3) I am not even sure it is in infrared.
You should read carefully the astro-stuff :)

Comment: Just a note, If it were the universe, it would not make sense for all the matter to be concentrated in the center due to the cosmological principle. There is no distinguished center around which mass would congregate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This picture was taken by the **WISE (Wide-field Infrared Survey Explorer)** space telescope. It is in deed an infrared picture of the entire universe but what you see in this line is our home galaxy, the Milky Way.

This telescope has taken infrared pictures of the entire Universe (as we see from the Earth) and joined them in this **full-sky view**.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide-field_Infrared_Survey_Explorer

Answer (score 1):

As other people said, what you see in that picture is a mosaic of images, centered in our Galaxy, produced with WISE observations in [infrared light](http://wise.ssl.berkeley.edu/gallery_infraastro.html). Astronomers have used a projection method, called Aitoff, to project the spherical sky into a 2-dimensional map.

For a more detailed explanation of the image, please follow this link:

http://wise.ssl.berkeley.edu/gallery_thesky.html

HTH,

Germán.

PS: Sorry that my reputation doesn't allow me to put more than two links.

Comment: Links about [WISE](http://wise.ssl.berkeley.edu/mission.html) and [Aitoff projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aitoff_projection).